# Update whole row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update a whole row without knowing the columns and rows...

Something like this:

```
UPDATE blabla SET blabla.* = tmp.* FROM tmp WHERE id = someid;
```

Has anyone ideas??

Thanks for answers

Comment: I don't think that's possible at all!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @MincongHuang So that you could have a reusable update statement (in a stored proc) that doesn't need to know the individual column names. As long as the column names match from one table to the other, or from the row json/object to the table, then it'd be fine... and since the PKs (presumably) match, there's no need to exclude even those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Postgres allows this.  One simple solution is two separate steps:

```
delete from blabla where id = someid;

insert into blabla
    select * from tmp where id = someid;
```

This assumes that the columns are defined in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to update all your columns names without knowing it. Please look at this link below. Although it is in mysql. I am sure, this will apply in postgresql

[SQL Updating Rows Without Knowing Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128335/sql-updating-rows-without-knowing-column-name)

I found  this link which uses CTE but it specifies column names

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45642/bulk-update-of-all-columns

Hope you find my answer useful.

Thanks,